# lilypond & tin whistle

Tags: lilypond, penny-whistle

I have prepared a songbook including notes, chords and lyrics. Some songs are good for the guitar as accompanying instrument, but some of them also are played well with the tin whistle. Are there any ideas, how to extend my scores by tin whistle diagrams?

Answer (score 3):

Woodwind diagrams are relatively simple with LilyPond [(see here)](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/woodwind-diagrams).

But it's *not* automatic; you do have to type in the tone holes used for each note.

```
\score {
    \new Staff {
         \set Staff.instrumentName = "Tin Whistle"
         
         \key d \major
         
         d'4^\markup {
             \woodwind-diagram #'tin-whistle
                 #'( (cc . (one two three four five six))
                     (lh . ()) (rh . ()) )
             }
         e'^\markup {
             \woodwind-diagram #'tin-whistle
                 #'( (cc . (one two three four five ))
                     (lh . ()) (rh . ()) )
             }
         fis'^\markup {
             \woodwind-diagram #'tin-whistle
                 #'( (cc . (one two three four ))
                     (lh . ()) (rh . ()) )
             }
         g'^\markup {
             \woodwind-diagram #'tin-whistle
                 #'( (cc . (one two three ))
                     (lh . ()) (rh . ()) )
             } 
         |
     }
     
     \layout {
         indent = 25
     }
}
```

[image: First four notes on tin whistle, with diagrams]

Comment: Is it possible to show partially occluded tone holes or the double tone holes of a baroque recorder?

Comment: In the link above: you can see how to show the various types of partially covered holes.  

As for the recorder, unfortunately there isn't currently a woodwind diagram template in LilyPond.    
You might be able to create one yourself if you know Scheme.  (I did try to learn Scheme myself for this exact reason, but I just couldn't understand it.  I ended up making my own diagrams by drawing them in LilyPond, which worked, but my coding was rather ugly.)

Comment: That looks pretty good!
But, as I have understood, I have to change all of my already prepared scores?
There isn't any dirty trick?

Comment: To simplify the coding:  You could make a function for each of the various fingering diagrams that you will use, and place these in a table that you _include_ when compiling.

You'll still have to make a function call after each note in the score to render each diagram though.  As far as I know there is currently no way to get LilyPond to read all of the notes and place the diagrams automatically.  (But you probably could get this to happen somehow if your computer science skills are really good.)